# stack trace interpretation on iOS

Tags: ios, stack-trace

Can someone help me make sense of the following iOS stacktrace?  I would love to know which UIViewController the issue originated from so I can pinpoint the issue:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31576f78 objc_msgSend + 15
1 CoreFoundation 0x3168b3fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
2 UIKit 0x31a9c6a1 -[UIApplication sendAction:fromSender:toTarget:forEvent:] + 64
3 UIKit 0x31a9c65b -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 46
4 UIKit 0x31a466a9 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 488
5 UIKit 0x31a4516d -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 168
6 UIKit 0x31a44a9d -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 96
7 UIKit 0x3196291d -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 336
8 UIKit 0x31a614a7 -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 174
9 UIKit 0x31a60d71 -[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] + 1608
10 UIKit 0x31a60637 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 106
11 UIKit 0x319f0d65 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 304
12 UIKit 0x31c21479 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 + 48
13 UIKit 0x3196cf55 _UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray + 176
14 UIKit 0x3196baa3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 898
15 UIKit 0x319787e9 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent + 28
16 UIKit 0x31978627 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 774
17 UIKit 0x319781f5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 88
18 UIKit 0x3195e695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
19 UIKit 0x3195df3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
20 GraphicsServices 0x32b6122b PurpleEventCallback + 882
21 CoreFoundation 0x31705523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
22 CoreFoundation 0x317054c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
23 CoreFoundation 0x31704313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
24 CoreFoundation 0x316874a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
25 CoreFoundation 0x3168736d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
26 GraphicsServices 0x32b60439 GSEventRunModal + 136
27 UIKit 0x3198ccd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
28 MyApp 0x000aa96b _mh_execute_header + 14699
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that stack trace we can deduce that the user tapped his finger on a text field.  If you only have one text field in your app, then you now know which UI element is involved, and maybe from that you can deduce which view controller is involved.

We can also see that the text field is sending its actions for becoming first responder.  If only one text field in your app has a target and action for the “Editing Did Begin” (`UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`) event, then you now know which UI element is involved, and maybe from that you can deduce which view controller is involved.

Otherwise, you cannot tell from that stack trace which view controller is involved.

Comment: Thanks, that does help me somewhat isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"I would love to know which UIViewController the issue originated from" <- that can't be known from a stacktrace only. Set a breakpoint on the function that crashed and/or build with debug symbols enabled.